# R: Using rnorm() ignoring NAs

Tags: r, na

In R, I am trying to generate a column of normally distributed random values based on columns existing in the dataframe.
As there are NAs in the columns I am using, NAs are returned in the new column.
**Is there a way I can ignore these NAs?**

I've used the built-in "airquality" data set as a dummy example to illustrate my problem as it includes NAs.

**Example Code:**

```
> airquality$random <- rnorm(n = nrow(airquality), mean = (50 + airquality$Ozone*1.2 + airquality$Solar.R*0.5 + airquality$Wind*3 + airquality$Temp*0.2), sd = 5)
Warning message:
In rnorm(n = nrow(airquality), mean = (50 + airquality$Ozone * 1.2 +  :
  NAs produced
> head(airquality)
  Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day   random
1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1 222.5487
2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2 191.8911
3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3 188.5913
4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4 273.7623
5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5      NaN
6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6      NaN
```

Rows 5 and 6 have NaN listed in the "random" column. I would like the "NA" values to be ignored (NAs could be in any column), so that row 5 would have a value of 100.22697*, and row 6 would have a value of 143.1274*

*these values were obtained by manually removing the NA columns from the code, but this isn't practical if I have a data set of thousands of rows and tens of columns.

Including `na.rm = TRUE` within the `mean = ()` section returns an error message:

```
> airquality$random <- rnorm(n = nrow(airquality), mean = (50 + airquality$Ozone*1.2 + airquality$Solar.R*0.5 + airquality$Wind*3 + airquality$Temp*0.2, na.rm = TRUE), sd = 5)
Error: unexpected ',' in "airquality$random <- rnorm(n = nrow(airquality), mean = (50 + airquality$Ozone*1.2 + airquality$Solar.R*0.5 + airquality$Wind*3 + airquality$Temp*0.2,"
```

If I put `na.rm = TRUE` at the end of the `rnorm()` section instead, it returns a different error message:

```
> airquality$random <- rnorm(n = nrow(airquality), mean = (50 + airquality$Ozone*1.2 + airquality$Solar.R*0.5 + airquality$Wind*3 + airquality$Temp*0.2), sd = 5, na.rm = TRUE)
Error in rnorm(n = nrow(airquality), mean = (50 + airquality$Ozone * 1.2 +  :
  unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `NA` elements in the columns.  An option is to convert the `NA` to 0 and then then use that in the calculation for the `mean` value as any arithmetic operation (`+`) with `NA` returns `NA`.  Also, the `na.rm = TRUE` in OP's code is doing nothing as it is an argument for the function `mean` and not for the parameter `mean` in `rnorm`

```
tmp <- replace(airquality, is.na(airquality), 0)
rnorm(n = nrow(tmp), mean = (50 + tmp$Ozone*1.2 + 
     tmp$Solar.R*0.5 + tmp$Wind*3 + tmp$Temp*0.2), sd = 5)
```

-output

```
[1] 230.54274 175.63684 191.09352 272.75306 108.56648 147.00571 263.74854 176.54437 138.34712 193.08597  91.91993 244.38106 246.75853 254.24543
 [15] 151.91976 278.17564 291.79558 166.25150 291.45414 124.37602  91.79503 285.40843 107.71572 180.18917 133.19906 230.15677  85.62659 135.79484
 [29] 290.33483 328.01940 268.59444 233.47771 240.75695 231.80327 182.09191 204.27378 239.15409 197.93795 222.74681 338.83640 305.89129 226.42353
 [43] 221.24226 190.21195 269.85521 260.70751 223.62116 319.93789 135.87652 171.82266 174.49938 159.01576 102.26742 128.54807 211.20653 147.96291
 [57] 147.09487 118.30181 137.67034 128.21919 155.11839 380.05157 276.10527 247.92156 142.26157 249.46309 308.70804 299.31816 344.92304 341.46871
 [71] 276.41410 162.72329 255.91151 224.55619 253.61126 139.57793 284.49149 277.79043 313.16401 273.82248 284.77515 109.29104 219.85529 249.98464
 [85] 331.40262 334.25997 155.60046 209.86921 308.24376 283.52677 287.17854 289.04658 173.97213 135.25243 148.04647 180.20284 135.46867 159.87413
 [99] 354.59991 317.06474 324.99885 207.30217 176.03234 243.66570 262.85251 251.59681 127.67214 161.26074 174.00305 177.45175 247.33476 246.72993
[113] 262.35549 136.78726 226.31141 259.75610 397.83067 293.34740 156.55135 289.65580 322.11876 301.68719 280.98863 297.88105 276.24682 251.60182
[127] 290.87347 188.69579 200.89883 246.30607 242.00302 232.00063 250.95042 279.32326 268.79634 235.51977 130.42808 170.68919 258.11289 241.38551
[141] 122.56174 239.76333 206.85573 230.98431 120.80214 214.62313 126.46720 135.36000 213.49774 178.97910 216.34848 175.17351 231.16300
```

---

Another option is to multiply the columns separately with the weights and then get the sum with `rowSums` where we can use `na.rm = TRUE`

```
mn <- rowSums(transform(airquality, Ozone = Ozone * 1.2,
   Solar.R = Solar.R * 0.5, Wind = Wind * 0.3, 
 Temp = Temp * 0.2)[c("Ozone", "Solar.R", "Wind", "Temp")], na.rm = TRUE)
rnorm(n = nrow(airquality), mean = mn, sd = 5)
```